# How do I centralize a class with display:inline-block?

Tags: css, html

I have couple of rectangle boxes aligning in 1 column straight and each boxes has a content in it.  Previously I have this below:

```
.frmPhases
{
    width:800px;
    border:solid 2px #CCC;
    background: #EEE;
    height:auto;
    padding:14px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

It displays just fine but with 1 flaw, its width isn't consistent.  So every new boxes come in, I have to set its width manually base on its content's maximum width.  (This requires id, which would make my CSS code REALLY long)

Now I improved the code to this:

```
.frmPhases
{
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid 2px #CCC;
    background: #EEE;
    height:auto;
    padding:14px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-top: 50p
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Now it has consistent width, but the rectangle boxes isn't centralized.  The only way to centralize it if I would to manually key in the margin-left, which looks fine but on different resolution it does not.  Any idea how to centralize it?

Comment: you could use a second container to centralize your elements.

Comment: How do you do that?  I tried `.centralize
{ display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }` and wrap it with the div boxes and it still wouldn't work though

Comment: Inline elements can be centered using `text-align:center` on the parent (/an ancestor) element.

Comment: i don't want to centralize any inline elements!

Comment: What @CBroe said. Note that `inline-block` elements are in inline flow and they can be centered by using `text-align: center` on the parent element. However you don't have to centralize **any** inline element, you could override the `text-align` property for `.frmPhases` like `.frmPhases { text-align: left; }`.